# How do i start building an autoclick bot for pubg mobile?

Tags: python, image-recognition, game-ai, open-ai

I want to make a bot which clicks the fire button on the mobile screen upon seeing an enemies head.

In pubg mobile which is an android game you have to control the fire button and the aim along with many other controls to kill an enemy or other players. I want to automate the fire button and everything else would be controlled by me, when I'll aim on a player's head the bot should click the fire button instantly.

So there are a few problems in this ,first one is that what if it shoots upon seeing my teammates head and other is what if there are  two players at once ,which will it shoot, for that it needs to shoot when my aim or the red crosshair is on the player's head.

I don't know how to get started , I need to make an image recognition app and an autoclicker and combine them both. How do I get started? Assuming that I only know basic python.

Comment: The problem is score kinda thing. Rest you can rely on a very high performance computer with Deep RL

Comment: I seen on some videos, people will sellotape a cross hair to the middle of there screen and use this instead as the raycast / the ejecting bullet always comes from the center in some games, for this game I am not sure, but I think a good initial way to go first would be narrowing down the problem to its simplest form, how can you make shooting more effective and efficient as a human player? So think in the game, when you see someones head on the screen, are all players the same height for example thus same Y Axis?